# Peltier heating/cooling

Tags: peltier

I live in a reasonable warm place, which requires me to run an AC all day, but I also need to use hot water for shower and other purposes. In this regard, I had the following idea, though I am unable to calculate the efficiency to know if it is practical.

I want to connect a few (maybe 20) Peltier devices with heat sinks on both sides such that the hot side circulates water into a thermally insulated storage tank and the cold side is connected to a circulator that is filled with a refrigerant and connects to a AC unit. This way, I am trying to use the full potential of the Peltier devices. Is this going to be efficient for the following purpose:

The water heating tank is 50 litres and needs to go upto 50C. 
The room to be cooled is 48m^3. 
I plan to keep the water storage unit right outside the room to be cooled so that there is less thermal wastage due to long pipes.

The ambient temperate is between 25C to 30C and I want to cool the room as much as possible. In particular, my goal is to try to utilize as much of the Peltier output as possible in the most efficient way.

My question, is this is a viable strategy in terms of efficiency? Where can I learn about how to calculate the efficiency of this setup vs a standard setup?

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: 'as much as possible' is not a specification. Start computing the power flows and the temperature differentials needed, and then look up some design charts online from Peltier manufacturers to see how many you need. Then look up figures for compression-cycle ACs to find out why they're used instead of Peltiers. With some pipework, you could probably harvest heat from the hot side of a conventional split AC for your hot water supply.